# Laravel - configuration cache on elastic beanstalk

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, laravel-5, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, ebextensions

I have a Laravel application running on an Elastic Beanstalk environment. 
Not having access to the database, S3 and SQS variables I did write a config on ebxtensions to copy some environment variables on the .env file during the deploy using the `echo` On a .sh hook file on post-deploy like this:

```
echo -e "AWS_BUCKET=$AWS_BUCKET" >> /var/app/current/.env
```

The .env file is correctly updated however another .sh hook that runs after that is completed that has the code:

```
php /var/app/current/artisan config:cache
```

And this saves the cached config file as the .env file was not updated yet.

Right now the config:cache command needs to be run manually after the deploy but I really want to make the process all automatic.

Any ideas why that happen?

Answer (score 4):

Process of EB deploy is very interesting, take a look at /var/log/eb-activity.log

```
  ++ /opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config container -k app_deploy_dir
  + EB_APP_DEPLOY_DIR=/var/app/current
  + '[' -d /var/app/current ']'
  + mv /var/app/current /var/app/current.old
  + mv /var/app/ondeck /var/app/current
  + nohup rm -rf /var/app/current.old
```

So, your config:cache running in previous environment which deleted after deploy.
You should use this post-hook in .ebextensions/01-post.config:

```
files:
  /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/post/01_create_cache.sh:
    mode: "000755"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      php /var/app/current/artisan config:cache >>/var/log/artisan_test.log
```

But use it carefully! It takes variables only from .env, **not** from EB VARIABLES!
Right way will be collect all variables to .env and than generate config cache.

```
files:
  /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/post/01_create_cache.sh:
    mode: "000755"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
    source /opt/elasticbeanstalk/support/envvars && /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/artisan config:cache >>/var/log/artisan_test.log
```